# edição de datagrid com navegacao via seta teclado

Tags: jquery, html5, bootstrap

Ola,

Estou convertendo um sistema desktop para formulario web, em uma das telas(de pedidos) tenho a facilidade do usuario digitar itens do pedido e com a seta pra baixo criar nova linha(item do pedido) e continuar digitando, sem precisar usar o mouse ou clicar em  botao.

Hoje utilizo jquery e bootstrap e nao encontrei nada para fazer algo semelhante, alguem tem alguma dica?

Comment: a dica he vc bindar o uso da tecla ( seta para baixo ) e dar um append em uma nova linha e essa linha vc ja tem o html dela como padrao em uma var do javascript. c vc quiser posso postar como resposta em um script simples que utiliza a tecla para baixo e a função append

Comment: pensei nisso, mas tambem me veio outras questoes, como aramzenar os dados para gravarcao, por exemplo...se tiver um exemplo para o pontape inicial agradeco

Comment: array , vc poe o name do form assim name="nomedocampo[]" dai pega o resultado como um array